# No build listed after changing jenkins job name

Tags: jenkins

I changed a job by changing the job name and adding some batch file commands(only some copy paste and db connections:none messing up with jenkins). It displays no build at first go which is expected, but now when i trigger a build, after getting finished it disappears.

Checked with the files and job builds in jenkins war location but can find all the builds there. But none is displayed in Jenkins UI.

Any specific reason?

Would add snapshots if required (Hope i am clear with my ques)

Comment: not sure what you mean by "it disappears".  Have you looked in the logs?

Comment: I had a similar problem some weeks ago. Restart Jenkins solved the problem.

Comment: @Vorsprung: by disappear i mean the job is not visible on the UI of jenkins but the job build is present in file system. and what exactly should i look for in logs?

Comment: also have you tried Micha's suggestion of restarting?  look for "unusual things" in the logs :)

Comment: restarting works fine! :D

Comment: Reloading the configuration would probably also work.

Comment: How exactly do we do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Restarting the jenkins resolved this. Need to look at any possible solution without restarting. Marking this as resolved since the issue is no more present.

Answer (score 0):

You have to go to Edit View and add that particular job to its corresponding view section,hope it will reappear the job in the jenkins UI.

Thanks